# Implementing ng-style in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, html

I'm using ng-style in ng-repeat. The ng-style will refer to the condition I made in the controller.
Below is my html snippet:

```
    <a class="item item-icon-left dark" ng-repeat="number in numbers">
      <span class="badge badge-balanced" ng-style="{'background' : bgColor}">{{number.status}}</span>
    </a>
```

Below is my js snippet:

```
.controller('Ctrl', function($rootScope) {

  $rootScope.numbers = [];
  $rootScope.bgColor = [];
  for(var i=1;i<=amt;i++)
  {
      var ticlist = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('storage' + i));
      $rootScope.numbers.push(ticlist);

      if (ticlist.status == "s1")
          $rootScope.bgColor[i-1] = "blue";
      else if (ticlist.status == "s2")
          $rootScope.bgColor[i-1] = "red";
      else if (ticlist.status == "s3")
          $rootScope.bgColor[i-1] = "green";
  }
)};
```

But the problem I encounter is the `bgColor` that showed will follow the last `ticlist.status`.
For example if I have 3 `ticlist.status` and they are 's1', 's2' and 's3', all of them will follow the color for 's3' which is green. If I have 's2', 's3' and 's2', all of them will be red. What changes can I made so that each of the `ticlist.status` has their own `bgColor`?

Comment: why are you using $rootScope?

Comment: Apart from usin $scope instead of $rootScope, you could add the bgColor property to the corresponding number so you can do number.bgColor in ngStyle or add bgColor[$index] to your current ng-style

Comment: the numbers property is the items I get from local storage. And it will be push to ticlist and one of the data is where I get ticlist.status.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways to fix this, but what about this?

CSS:

```
.s1 {
    background-color: red;
}
.s2 {
    background-color: green;
}
.s3 {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

HTML:

```
<a class="item item-icon-left dark" ng-repeat="number in numbers">
    <span class="badge badge-balanced {{number.status}}">{{number.status}}</span>
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks. But is there an answer using js?